# how to assemble external artifacts into one global directory with the maven-assembly-plugin (or otherwise)

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am experimenting with Maven and I am trying to mavenize a project originally build with shell scripts.

With the Maven rule-of-thumb: one project, one artifact, I created the following structure:

```
<PROJECT>
  <MODULE-1>
  <MODULE-2>
  <MODULE-3>
  ..
  <MODULE-N>
  <RESOURCES>     
  <DISTRIB>
```

The RESOURCES module is structured as follows:

```
<RESOURCES>/src/main/resources/<MODULE-1>/bin
<RESOURCES>/src/main/resources/<MODULE-1>/lib
<RESOURCES>/src/main/resources/<MODULE-1>/doc
<RESOURCES>/src/main/resources/<MODULE-2>/bin
<RESOURCES>/src/main/resources/<MODULE-2>/lib
<RESOURCES>/src/main/resources/<MODULE-2>/doc
...
<RESOURCES>/src/main/resources/<MODULE-N>/bin
<RESOURCES>/src/main/resources/<MODULE-N>/lib
<RESOURCES>/src/main/resources/<MODULE-N>/doc
```

The reason for doing it this way was that the resources above are needed at runtime, not compile-time and they are mostly property files, config files and shell scripts to invoke the various jar-files. For the final resources step, I wanted to combine the subdirectories into one global bin/lib/doc directory. However, I do not see an option in the assembly descriptor to strip of the prefix of the modules to get to what I want:

```
 <RESOURCES>/target/resources/bin
 <RESOURCES>/target/resources/lib
 <RESOURCES>/target/resources/doc
```

where *bin* would contain all the files found in the /src/main/resources//bin directory, /src/main/resources//bin directory etc. Similarly for *lib*, *doc*.

My question: should I have a:

```
<MODULE-1>/src/external/resources/bin
<MODULE-1>/src/external/resources/lib
<MODULE-1>/src/external/resources/doc
...
<MODULE-N>/src/external/resources/bin
<MODULE-N>/src/external/resources/lib
<MODULE-N>/src/external/resources/doc
```

structure instead, that I would then access through a dependency-set? These files should not be part of the jar-file of the various modules and therefore cannot be stored in src/main/resources of their respective projects. Or is what I want to achieve doable by using some other maven plugin instead?

In the DISTRIB module I would combine the output of the RESOURCES module with the JAR-files and dependencies to create a directory structure that would then be used with a packaging tool (Solaris package and WiX installer).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the pom's you have created ? Cause i don't understand what the "RESOURCES" module is?

Comment: The RESOURCES module is the module where I have stored all the global resources (runtime scripts, configuration examples, documentation) of the various modules (to track where it came from). For the final packaging and installer, the files obviously need to be together, so I created a separate module to do so.

Answer (score 0):

In the pom fort he resources module set the source directory to something other than /src/main/resources/ so that it does not copy them to the target folder. Then use the [Maven Resources Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) to copy the resource files to target/bin and target lib etc.

e.g.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target/bin/</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
            <directory>src/external/resources/bin</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
        </resources>
    </configuration>
    </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target/lib/</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
            <directory>src/external/resources/lib</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
        </resources>
    </configuration>
    </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>`
```